# Puts statement is not printing the messages to the console

Tags: ruby, rspec, pageobjects

I am placing a few `puts` statements in my script. But the messages are not printed; the script is passing through these statements. I observe the moment execution goes into rake `puts` is not working throughout the flow.

In spec helper

```
class Testbed
puts "Inside test bed" // This puts is printed
some code
some code
some code
some code
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  puts "In side rspec config" // This puts is printed
   config.color = true
   config.tty = true
some code
some code
some code
some code
end

config.before(:all) do
    puts "in before all"//not printed
```

None of the `puts` statements here is printing an output. My `puts` in Page Object, Spec files are not considered.

Can any one suggest a workaround for this?

Comment: Do you have any specs?

Comment: I think you need to post a minimally working example so that people can reproduce it, how are you calling the code where your `puts` doesn't get printed?

Answer (score 4):

Consider where `puts` outputs by default. [It uses `$stdout`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) unless you've told it to [use a different channel](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-puts), such as:

```
File.open('foo', 'w') do |fo|
  fo.puts 'bar'
end
```

When it's using `$stdout` or `STDOUT`, a calling program, especially one that's using Ruby in a sub-shell, can capture the output and do what it wants with it. That's a feature of the OS. If I had code this code saved in 'test.rb':

```
puts 'foo'
```

and called it from the shell:

```
ruby /path/to/test.rb > /some/file.txt
```

The output would be piped to /some/file.txt and I wouldn't see it at the console. Similarly, if I had a second app that called the first:

```
output = %x[ruby /path/to/test.rb]
```

The variable `output` would contain the text `'foo'`, captured from the sub-shell's STDOUT being rerouted.

There are a lot of ways to do this, from using backticks or `%x[...]` to using [`popen`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-c-popen) or pipes in a regular `open` command to the methods in Open3. Discussing filenames when opening a file, the [IO docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html) say:

> A string starting with "|" indicates a subprocess. The remainder of the string following the "|" is invoked as a process with appropriate input/output channels connected to it.

So, asking us why `puts` isn't outputting to your console isn't easily answered, but you can see it's easily done if something is calling your code besides Ruby directly.

Comment: How can I print a variable? `branchName = options[:name]
  puts(message: "Creating a new branch named:")`. I want to print the branchName variable in this statement.

Answer (score 0):

> Can any one suggest a workaround for this?

First, how about paying attention to all your errors?

```
`<main>': undefined method `config' for RSpec:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Your code does this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  puts "In side rspec config" // This puts is printed
  config.color = true
  config.tty = true
end
```

...and the config variable is only defined inside the block.  But then you write this:

```
config.before(:all) do
  puts "in before all"//not printed
end
```

That code isn't inside the block, so the config variable doesn't exist.

Next, before() only executes *before* other tests--but you have no tests, as the rspec output shows:

```
$ rspec 1.rb 
Inside test bed
In side rspec config
No examples found.  #*********HERE


Finished in 0.00032 seconds (files took 0.0879 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures   #*******HERE
```

Try this:

```
class Testbed
  puts "Inside test bed" #This puts is printed
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  puts "In side rspec config" #This puts is printed
  config.color = true
  config.tty = true

  config.before(:all) do
    puts "in before all" #?????
  end
end

#Here is an rspec test:

RSpec.describe do
  it "some test" do
  end
end
```

...

```
~/ruby_programs$ rspec 1.rb 
Inside test bed
In side rspec config
in before all   #Yeah!!
.

Finished in 0.00073 seconds (files took 0.4294 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```